# PHP fopen keeps failing for input URL

Tags: php, fopen

I'm playing around with PHP and am trying to run this code sample:

```
<?php
  // $target = "http://www.example.com/";
  $target = "http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/hello_world.html";
  $output = "";

  // Fetch the file.
  if($file_handle = fopen($target, 'r')) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($file_handle, 4096)) !== false) {
      $output = $output . $buffer;
    }
    if(!feof($file_handle)) {
      $output = "Error: Unexpected fgets fail\n";
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
  } else {
    die("Error: fopen failed\n");
  }
  echo $output;
?>
```

I keep getting this error for the above URL:

```
Warning: fopen(http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/hello_world.html/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in <code.php> on line 3
```

However, the code works for other URLs like "http://www.example.com", "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview" etc.

Please help me debug this.

Comment: How about `http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/hello_world.html` (removing the trailing slash `/` at the end) ?

Comment: If you open in browser: `http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/hello_world.html/` it will say 404 not found, while `http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/hello_world.html` will open properly. so remove last `/` from URL

Comment: Also, what is the point of `rawurlencode($target)` ? By the way, if this still doesn't work with `fopen()`, it might be disallowed for bots.

Comment: Let me update the code. Also not adding the trailing slash gives me the same problem. I was the using rawurlencode, to debug the code in the first place. I have removed it from the code sample.

Comment: @ServingQuarantineperiod Hi. Please try running the Php code at least rather than just visiting the website.

Comment: @nice_dev I don't know. That website is for a text book explaining bots etc. It seems bizarre why they would put in those restrictions.

Comment: About the rawurlencode, in the earlier version of the code: I am new to php, so used that function thinking it's necessary to use with any URL. I didn't know you only use it with part of URL with params.

Answer (score 2):

As suspected, the site does not allow bots to read data from it. As a workaround, you can simulate a browser user agent to make the site believe as though the request is coming from an actual browser. Also, reading using `fopen()` is tedious. If you just want to capture the response entirely, `curl` is a much better option.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

try{
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/hello_world.html');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36");
  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  if(curl_errno($ch) !== 0){
     throw new \Exception(curl_error($ch));
  }

  curl_close($ch);
  echo $response;
}catch(\Exception $e){
  die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```